# Changing Font Size of Numbers in Turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, font-size, python-turtle

I am able to change the font size of normal characters, but how can I change the font size of numbers? I want the numbers to be the same size as  "You can live you're life the way you want".

```
    t.color('white')
    t.goto(0, 0)
    t.write("29", font=(20))
    t.penup()

    turtle.color('white')
    turtle.goto(0,50)
    turtle.write("You can live you're life the way you want", font=(20))
    t.penup()
```

I tried using font. I couldn't find any useful information online.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from your snippet what is really happening, but several things spring to mind looking at the code you show:

1. The `color` is `"white"`. This could mean that you won't see white text on a white background.
2. You use `font=(20)` which doesn't look like what the `write()` method is looking for in the `font` parameter.
3. You sometimes use `t.` and at other times use `turtle.`. These could be different objects.

I tried this code and I can see the two pieces of text in different places at different font sizes:

```py
def show_text(t):
    t.penup()
    t.color('black')
    t.goto(0, 200)
    t.write("29", font=('arial',30))

    t.color('black')
    t.goto(0,150)
    t.write("You can live you're life the way you want", font=('arial',40))

show_text(turtle)
```

**Update:** Removed the unneeded penup/pendown on suggestion from @cdlane

Comment: The `write()` method operates independently of the pen being up or down.  (Or the turtle being hidden or visible.)  It's not drawing the text in a plotter sense, unfortunately.

Comment: @cdlane so my function just needs a `penup()` at the start.

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming we're trying to avoid the `goto()` commands from leaving lines.